# TypeError: this.props.onIncrement is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I,m totally new in react and try to create counter app but when i try to move counters component  functionality to the main App.js i receive an error in counter component. I will be very thankful for help
[image]

**Counters component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';
class Counters extends Component {
render() { 
    return (
    <div>
        <button 
        className="btn btn-primary btn-large m-2" 
        onClick={this.props.OnReset}
        >Reset
        </button>

       {this.props.counters.map(counter => (
       <Counter 
       key={counter.id} 
       onDelete ={this.props.OnDelete} 
       onIncrement ={this.props.OnIncrement}
       counter={counter}
       />
      ))}
    </div>
    );
}
```

}

**part from App.js**

```
handleIncrement = counter=>{
 const counters = [...this.state.counters];
 const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
 counters[index] = {...counter}; //counter object clone
 counters[index].value++; 
 this.setState({counters});};

render(){
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <NavBar/>
    <main className="container">
      <Counters
      counters={this.state.counters}
      onReset = {this.handleReset}
      onDelete ={this.handleDelete} 
      onIncrement ={this.handleIncrement}
      />
    </main>
  </React.Fragment>
);}
```

Comment: where is "this.handleIncrement" ? did you declare that function?

Comment: `
handleIncrement = counter=>{
     const counters = [...this.state.counters];
     const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
     counters[index] = {...counter}; 
     counters[index].value++; 
     this.setState({counters});
 };
`

Comment: you should bind "this" in order to make it work in the call back i.e ( this.handleIncrement =this.handleInvrement.bind(this) ). Find more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)